# Jenkins mvn command in PIPELINES doesn't update the metadata.xml of artifactory

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-3, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

we just migrate all our MVN jobs to multibranch Pipeline job.

the original Maven command was **clean deploy -P integration-tests deploy -DupdateReleaseInfo=true**

we used the **updateReleaseInfo** flag to make sure the metadat.xml will be updated.

once we migrated to PIPELINE we run the same command , but looks like the flag **updateReleaseInfo** has no affect  , and the metadata.xml is not updated.

```
<latest>1.156</latest>
<release>2.1</release>
```

once I run the original Maven job again the metadata in artifactory updated to

```
<latest>2.1</latest>
<release>2.1</release>
```

we used Jenkins 2.46.3 
Maven Integration plugin 3.0
Maven version 3.3.9

any idea for this issue ?

here is my code

```
stage('Deploy') {
                when {
                    anyOf { branch 'master' }
                }
                steps {
                    mavenTask tasks: 'clean deploy -DupdateReleaseInfo=true', localRepo: 'true'
                }
        }
```

and my maven task from the shared library

```
def call(Map map = [:]) {

    def params = [
            tasks           : '',
            localRepo : ''
    ] << map

    def tasks = params.tasks
    def localRepo = params.localRepo

    if (localRepo == 'true') {
        mvnLocalRepo = '-Dmaven.repo.local=$WORKSPACE/.repository'
    } else {
        mvnLocalRepo = ''
    }

    configFileProvider(
            [configFile(fileId: '11111-22222-33333', targetLocation: './settings.xml')]) {
        sh "mvn -s $WORKSPACE/settings.xml $mvnLocalRepo $tasks "
    }
}
```

Comment: Your command line contains several useless definitions. `install deploy` can be reduced to simply `deploy` cause `install` life cycle part is part of the life cycle by using `deploy`. Furthermore I don't understand why you are using a second call of the life cycle `deploy`?

Comment: the original command was clean deploy , I added the install since I found a blog that explain that the add of the install stap  , solve this issue.

I will update my post.
I have only one call fro deploy in the bash command

Comment: Are you building & deploying a Maven Plugin? Because `<latest>` can be used _only_ for plugins, it's not intended for other types of artifacts. `-DupdateReleaseInfo` is supposed to update only `<release>` tag and again - its primary usage is for plugins. You should use tools idiomatically.

Comment: Nope it's a regular lib that other projects used. Once it's not update other projects will not get the latest version

Comment: And they shouldn't. This is not how Maven is supposed to be used. You need to always hardcode the versions of your dependencies and never rely on auto-updates. Otherwise your builds are not reproducible and can spontaneously fail or worse - introduce bugs.

Comment: this is another discussion  , our workflow , is that each build use the latest artifacts without the need to update the pom all the time.
in Previous MVN job the metadata was updated and now it's not ...

Comment: Can you please share a snippet of your pipeline script? Are you using the Artifactory Pipeline API or an sh step?

Comment: HI Eyal
I am using  sh step , will add the snippet to my question

Comment: Just to make sure, are you deploying POM file as well or only JAR/WAR?

Comment: I deploy jar and pom

Comment: @MorLajb Just to check with you if you have got any solution for problem mentioned above? We are also facing same problem.

Comment: hi @RohitBatta , sorry but I don't have any update on this , and since I moved to another company , don't face this issue any more. good luck